# Prove that the sequence is bounded above

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

The questions is as follows
Given the sequence $$a_{n+1} =\sqrt{\frac{8a_{n}^2+1681}{9}}$$
where: $$a_1 = M$$ and $M$ can be assumed to not be larger than 30 and non-negative (Because M is considered to be a length not larger than 30m.
Previously in the question one was to assume that the sequence was converging and find its limit which I deduced to be 41. The next step is to show that the sequence is upper bounded which I cannot bring myself to do. By looking at the sequence it seems to grow without bound and it makes me doubt the assumption that it converges to begin with considering it seems to grow without end. 
Would it be too much to ask for a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: What if we consider $b_n=a_n^2$ instead? The recurrence would get a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_1\leq45$ by assumption.

Assume $a_n\leq45$.

Therefore,

$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{8a_n^2+1681}{9}}\leq\sqrt{\frac{8\cdot45^2+1681}{9}}\leq45$

The last inequality is shown through simple calculation.

Thus, $a_n\leq45\forall n$ by induction. Thus, the sequence is bounded above.

Answer (score 0):

Use mathematical induction.

We have $a_1<41$. Suppose $a_n<41$, and deduce that $$a_{n+1}<\sqrt{\frac{8\times41^2+1681}{9}}=41.$$